# Extracting a parameter from a single object

Tags: javascript, parameters, extract, json, reddit

I am Using `JavaScript(not JQuery)`, what is the best method for extracting the parameter Name from the following object?

```
Object {kind: "t3", data: Object}
data
:
Object
approved_by
:
null
archived
:
false
author
:
"mik3br"
author_flair_css_class
:
null
author_flair_text
:
null
banned_by
:
null
clicked
:
false
created
:
1468895158
created_utc
:
1468866358
distinguished
:
null
domain
:
"i.reddituploads.com"
downs
:
0
edited
:
false
from
:
null
from_id
:
null
from_kind
:
null
gilded
:
0
hidden
:
false
hide_score
:
false
id
:
"4tgmha"
is_self
:
false
likes
:
null
link_flair_css_class
:
null
link_flair_text
:
null
locked
:
false
media
:
null
media_embed
:
Object
mod_reports
:
Array[0]
name
:
"t3_4tgmha"
num_comments
:
21
num_reports
:
null
over_18
:
false
permalink
:
"/r/funny/comments/4tgmha/this_killed_me/"
post_hint
:
"link"
preview
:
Object
quarantine
:
false
removal_reason
:
null
report_reasons
:
null
saved
:
false
score
:
1387
secure_media
:
null
secure_media_embed
:
Object
selftext
:
""
selftext_html
:
null
stickied
:
false
subreddit
:
"funny"
subreddit_id
:
"t5_2qh33"
suggested_sort
:
null
thumbnail
:
"http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/f-1tMuhEp_mDpRYR-XpA83xgtEQeqp6tKj-ydZ24yUI.jpg"
title
:
"This killed me"
ups
:
1387
url
:
"https://i.reddituploads.com/03b691b0e5ab4eb3b524f54d31de90a1?fit=max&amp;h=1536&amp;w=1536&amp;s=7bceab738dc25ea13b66ff0f389024ca"
user_reports
:
Array[0]
visited
:
false
__proto__
:
Object
kind
:
"t3"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please give a real code snippet of what you've tried and what you're having difficulties with

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an object as

```
var obj = {kind: "t3", data: {abc: "xyx", cde: "zys"}};
```

Then you can access the parameter `kind` from object as  `obj.kind` or `abc` as `obj.data.abc`.

I suppose this is what you want.

```js
var obj = {kind: "t3", data: {abc: "xyx", cde: "zys"}};
alert(obj.kind);
alert(obj.data.abc);
```